# "from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import" throws error "DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

Tags: python, numpy

I am testing my numpy installation. In Python prompt I tried writing `import numpy`. However it is giving the below error. I am using Anaconda. I had installed numpy using conda command `conda install numpy`

Python version 3.7.7
numpy version 1.18.1
OS is Win 10

Log:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.7 from "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.18.1" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```